# Handling White Space on Automatic Zip Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip

I'm currently working on a special zipping program for my company, but I'm a beginner in shell script, so I'm stuck in something.
Manually, there are no problem in zipping a file with whitespaces, I just need to add `\` before them, for example using the following file: `test for zip.txt` 
The correct argument for zipping it would be `test\ for\ zip.txt`.
Is there any function I could use check the string and add the `\` automatically? 
 
For reproduction purposes, here is how I'm getting the name:

```
listFiles=$(ls -p | grep -v /) #Yes I know, appending with ls isn't the best solution.
IFS=$'\n' #To make sure files with whitespace are properly handled.
```

```
#This will list the files for the user to choose.
choice=''
i=1
for j in $listFiles
    do
        echo "$i.$j"
        file[i]=$j
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
```

Example files: 
test.txt 
stack.txt 
to zip.txt

```
Output of the FOR LOOP: 
1. test.txt
2. stack.txt
3. test for zip.txt
```

Finally, the user then chooses the file with the following command and then, the chosen file will be stored for future use in the zipping program:

```
read -p "Insert the number of the desired file: " choice
echo -e "The selected file is: '${file[$choice]}'"
```

Comment: Make `listFiles` an array, not a string, then use `"${listFiles[@]}"`

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

Handling filenames with whitespace generally requires proper use of [quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Quotes tell the shell not to perform Word Splitting which is the thing that typically causes whitespace in filenames to break your programs.

To start, accessing your files with a glob and storing them in an array will preserve each filename as its own element regardless of any whitespace or other special characters in the filename.

`listFiles=( *.txt )`

Then you can iterate the array to access each file:

```
i=1
#         THESE QUOTES ARE IMPORTANT
for j in "${listFiles[@]}"
    do
        [[ -f "$j" ]] || continue # protects against empty array
        echo "$i.$j"
        file[i]=$j
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
```

And finally, when you get a choice from the user, make sure to quote all references to their choice.

```
cat ${file[choice]} # Bad, breaks if filename has whitespace in it
cat "${file[choice]}" # Good, safely handles whitespace
```